Multiplication map of algebras of monoidal ($\infty$)-categories
Lurie defines (DAG-II, Def. 1.1.2) a monoidal $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$ as a coCartesian fibration $\mathcal{C}^\otimes \to N(\Delta)^\text{op}$ satisfying the Segal condition, i.e. such that for each $n \geq 0$, the functors $\mathcal{C}^\otimes_{[n]} \to \mathcal{C}^\otimes_{\{i, i+1\}}$ associated to $[1] \stackrel{\{i, i+1\}}{\hookrightarrow} [n]$ determines an equivalence of $\infty$-categories
$$
\mathcal{C}_{[n]}^\otimes \to \mathcal{C}^\otimes_{\{0, 1\}} \times \dots \times \mathcal{C}^\otimes_{\{n-1, n\}} \simeq (\mathcal{C}^\otimes_{[1]})^n.
$$
In particular, intuitively this recovers a "tensor product" map given by the following composite
$$
- \otimes - : \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C} \simeq \mathcal{C}^\otimes_{\{0,1\}} \times \mathcal{C}^\otimes_{\{1,2\}} \stackrel{\simeq}{\leftarrow} \mathcal{C}^\otimes_{[2]} \to \mathcal{C}^\otimes_{\{0,2\}} \simeq \mathcal{C}, \quad (X,Y) \mapsto X \otimes Y.
$$
He then defines (DAG-II, Def. 1.1.14) an algebra object in $\mathcal{C}^\otimes$ as a lax monoidal functor $N(\Delta)^\text{op} \to \mathcal{C}^\otimes$, i.e. a section of $\mathcal{C}^\otimes \to N(\Delta)^\text{op}$ satisfying certain properties.
My problem. Taking an algebra object $A$, I can't at all understand how to get a multiplication $A({[1]}) \otimes A([1]) \to A([1])$ compatible with the monoidal structure on $\mathcal{C} := \mathcal{C}^\otimes_{[1]}$.
I tried to work out also the $1$-categorical case but I'm still stuck; in particular, from my understanding, morally an algebra as above picks out an object $A([1]) \in \mathcal{C} = \mathcal{C}_{[1]}^\otimes$, and picks out $n$ objects $A([n]) = (c_1, \dots, c_n) \in \mathcal{C}^\otimes_{[n]} \simeq \prod^n \mathcal{C}^\otimes_{[1]}$; the lax monoidal condition (I think) should force $c_1 \simeq \dots \simeq c_n \simeq A([1])$. Moreover, for a map $f: [m] \to [n] \in \Delta$, I think that one should get that
\begin{align*}
f^\ast : \mathcal{C}^{\times n} \simeq \mathcal{C}^\otimes_{[n]} & \to \mathcal{C}^\otimes_{[n]} \simeq \mathcal{C}^{\times m} \\
(c_1, \dots , c_n) & \mapsto (c_{f(1)} \otimes \dots \otimes c_{f(0)}, \dots , c_{f(m)} \otimes \dots \otimes c_{f(m-1)})
\end{align*}
at least at an intuitive level, and that the map $A(f) : A([n]) \to A([m])$ should somehow be compatible with the above maps.
In particular, the multiplication map $A([1]) \otimes A([1]) \to A([1])$ should come from the map $d^1: [1] \stackrel{\{0,2\}}{\hookrightarrow} [2]$, but I don't see how (I'm still stuck at one "categorical level higher", i.e. on $\mathcal{C}^\otimes$ but I can't understand how to induce a multiplication on $A$, if that makes sense; similarly also for the unit map $1 \to A$). I'm sorry if this question is trivial but I'm not too familiar with these objects and concepts.

First a bit of a side remark: if $f\colon[m]\to[n]$ is a morphism in $\Delta$, then $f^*\colon\mathcal{C}^{\otimes n}\to\mathcal{C}^{\otimes n}$ is given by
$$
f^*(c_1,\ldots,c_n)\simeq(c_{f(0)+1}\otimes c_{f(0)+2}\otimes\ldots\otimes c_{f(1)}, \ldots, c_{f(n-1)+1}\otimes c_{f(n-1)+2}\otimes\ldots\otimes c_{f(n)}).
$$
(Of course, you can also reverse the order in which we take the tensors, e.g. you could write $(c_{f(1)}\otimes\ldots\otimes c_{f(0)+1}$, but I find it easier to keep things ''in order''. At the end of the day, the important thing is that you stay consistent, and by keeping things in order I never have to think about permutations of factors once I start combining tensor products.)
The reason is as follows: this is essentially how we define the tensor product on $\mathcal{C}$: we are just given a cocartesian fibration $\mathcal{C}^\otimes\to\Delta^\mathrm{op}$, and we declare, given $(c_1,\ldots,c_n)\in\mathcal{C}^\otimes$, that $c_1\otimes \ldots\otimes c_n$ is the target of the cocartesian morphism in $\mathcal{C}^\otimes$ whose source is $(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$, and that is lying above the morphism $[n]\to[1]$ in $\Delta^\mathrm{op}$ that is given by $[1]\to[n], 0\mapsto 0, 1\mapsto n$ in $\Delta$. Therefore, if $\alpha_{ij}\colon[1]\to[n], 0\mapsto i, 1\mapsto j$ is a map in $\Delta$, then $\alpha_{ij}$ factors as $[1]\to[j-i]\hookrightarrow[n]$. The latter map is inert, and hence induces a projection map $(c_1,\ldots,c_n)\mapsto (c_{i+1},\ldots,c_j)$ (we will explain this in a moment). The former map then sends this to the tensor product $c_{i+1}\otimes\ldots\otimes c_j$. How do we know that inert maps induce such projection maps? Well, the components of an element of $\mathcal{C}^{\otimes (j-i)}$ are, by the Segal condition, given by the images of that element under the maps $\alpha_{01},\ldots,\alpha_{j-i-1,j-i}$. The inclusion $\iota\colon[j-i]\to[n], k\mapsto k+i$ satisfies
$$
\iota\circ\alpha_{k,k+1}=\alpha_{k+i,k+i+1}
$$
and therefore $\iota$ must send $(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ to $(c_{i+1},\ldots,c_{j})$. Given a general $f\colon [m]\to[n]$, we have $f\circ\alpha_{k,k+1}\colon [1]\to[n]$ to have a similar form as the composite $[1]\to[j-i]\hookrightarrow[n]$ that we considered above, and hence the $k$-th component of $f^*(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ has the form we wrote out above.
Now, onto your actual question: by lax monoidality of $A$, $A$ must preserve all cocartesian lifts of inert maps in $\Delta^\mathrm{op}$, so in particular it satisfies $A(\alpha_{k,k+1})\simeq\alpha^*_{k,k+1}$, which is the projection map $\mathcal{C}^{\otimes n}\to\mathcal{C}$ onto the $(k+1)$-th component (where $\alpha_{k,k+1}\colon [1]\to[n]$). Since there is only one element in $\Delta^\mathrm{op}$ that lives in level $n$ over $\Delta^\mathrm{op}$ (whereas in $\mathcal{C}^\otimes$, this holds for all of $\mathcal{C}^{\otimes n}$), this already forces $A[n]\simeq(A[1],\ldots,A[1])$.
Now, if $f\colon [1]\to[n], 0\mapsto 0,1\mapsto n$ is a map in $\Delta$, then $A(f)$ is a certain map $(A[1],\ldots,A[1])\to A[1]$ in $\mathcal{C}^\otimes$, living over the map $f$ in $\Delta^\mathrm{op}$. Every such map factors uniquely as a composite of $f^*\colon (A[1],\ldots,A[1])\to A[1]\otimes\ldots\otimes A[1]$, followed by a certain map $A[1]\otimes\ldots\otimes A[1]\to A[1]$ in $\mathcal{C}^{\otimes 1}\simeq\mathcal{C}$. This follows by the defining property of cocartesian fibrations: every map in $\mathcal{C}^\otimes$ lying over a map $g$ in $\Delta^\mathrm{op}$ factors uniquely as a cocartesian lift of $g$ followed by a map lying over an identity morphism. Since the information of $f^*\colon(A[1],\ldots, A[1])\to A[1]$ is only dependent on $\mathcal{C}^\otimes$ and hence ''fixed'' in this sense, $A(f)$ is determined by the single map $A[1]\otimes \ldots \otimes A[1]\to A[1]$ that was part of it.
Now, if $f\colon [m]\to[n]$ is a general map, we can use the same trick as above (postcomposing with the maps $\alpha_{k,k+1}$ that induce projections towards single components) to conclude that $A(f)$ is determined by maps
$$
(A[1])_{f(0)+1}\otimes(A[1])_{f(0)+2}\otimes\ldots\otimes (A[1])_{f(1)}\to A[1]\\
\vdots\\
(A[1])_{f(n-1)+1}\otimes(A[1])_{f(n-1)+2}\otimes\ldots\otimes (A[1])_{f(n)}\to A[1]
$$
Here, I wrote $(A[1])_k$ to denote the $k$-th copy of $A[1]$ in the object $A[n]\simeq(A[1],\ldots,A[1])$ to make it clearer what is going on here. You can also see this by immediately applying the unique factoring of $A(f)$ into $f^*$ followed by some other morphism in $\mathcal{C}^{\otimes m}$, and you would find the same result.
We have $A[0]\simeq\mathbf{1}_\mathcal{C}$ because $\mathcal{C}^{\otimes 0}$ only consists of a single object, corresponding to the unit of the monoidal structure on $\mathcal{C}$. Then the unique map $[1]\to[0]$ in $\Delta$ gives a map $A[0]\to A[1]$ in $\mathcal{C}$, which is the unit of the algebra. Expected properties such as right and left unitality of the algebra structure follow from combinatorics in the category $\Delta$: for instance, the map $[1]\to [2], 0\mapsto 0, 1\mapsto 2$ encodes the multiplication in $A$, and $[2]\to[1], 0\mapsto 0, 1\mapsto 0, 2\mapsto 1$ can via similar "componentwise" considerations as above seen to induce $A[1]\to (A[1],A[1]), a\mapsto (1,a)$. Then we find that $1\cdot a\simeq a$ because the composite $[1]\to[2]\to[1]$ of these maps is the identity morphism on $[1]$.

Thank you very much for the detailed answer!
